# Assigning I/O Unit Number to a String Variable

Tags: fortran

I have some FORTRAN code that creates a .dll that is called from a couple different projects.  In some cases, I want to write the output to a .txt file, and in other cases the output is passed back from the .dll, depending on the project that is calling it.  What I am looking for is a way to handle the `WRITE` statement the same in either case.  That is, I'm looking for something like

```
SUBROUTINE MYPROGRAM(PROJECTFLAG,MYSTRING)

IF (PROJECTFLAG.EQ.1) THEN
  OPEN(1,FILE='RESULTS.TXT')
ELSEIF (PROJECTFLAG.EQ.2) THEN
  OPEN(1,MYSTRING) !THIS SYNTAX DOES NOT WORK
ENDIF

...

WRITE (1,*) OUTPUTDATA

END SUBROUTINE
```

As I noted, the syntax I have above doesn't work.  **Is it possible to `OPEN` a variable for `WRITE`ing like this, or can you only `OPEN` files?**

I know I could move my if block down, and do something like

```
IF (PROJECTFLAG.EQ.1) THEN
  WRITE(1,*) OUTPUTDATA
ELSEIF (PROJECTFLAG.EQ.2) THEN
  WRITE(MYSTRING,*) OUTPUTDATA
ENDIF
```

but the code in the actual project is obviously much more complex, and my goal is to have the same `WRITE` statement used, regardless of where I want to write the data to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not possible. The compiler must know, whether the write statement is for internal I/O or external I/O. In the first case you supply an integer (the unit number) in the other case you supply a character string.

Also, you cannot `open` a character string.

Perhaps you could write a generic function and call it either with the unit number or with the string?

Comment: Thanks.  I was doing some more research after I posted the Q, and I found [this site for Intel compilers](https://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/doclib/stdxe/2013/composerxe/compiler/fortran-mac/GUID-A4E25114-C10A-486E-B835-DEA35B371472.htm), which states exactly what you have.  Writing a generic function might work, I'll look into that.